# Laravel 5.4 Passport restrict the use of a Personal Access Token on a specific route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

So i have an API that i have been developing and some of the routes obviously need a user instance in order for me to fully complete the request on the server side.

What i am wondering is, is there a way to restrict certain routes in laravel so that it would require a full oauth token instead of just a personal access token. 
The only way at the moment i can see to filter this out is by adding Token Scopes. However I rather avoid adding scopes just to filter out the use of a Personal Access Token vs a client....

Thoughts...

Thanks

Citti

Answer (score 1):

Well as I understand, Personal Access Tokens are assigned with certain user. Here is from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens):

> Once you have created a personal access client, you may issue tokens for a given user using the  createToken method on the User model instance.

Personal Access Token is issued for specific user:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Creating a token without scopes...
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

This way, you are making a request with `Bearer $token` to a `/user` route:

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return Auth::user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

And the response will be exact user, for whom the PAT was created. So all you need is protect your route with `auth:api` middleware

Comment: that would return the authenticated user if a user was authenticated on the API server. APIs should be stateless though. no one could technically be logged in, which is why you would have to distinguish via the token passed...

Comment: Ok @Citti so when a user is not logged in and tries to access this route let say via api request, then he gets `Unauthorized 401` response. So may be in this case show login popup or so

Comment: Yea i get it, i rather not do that though. My application can handle both scenarios right... If you want to take action on behalf of a user create a client and go through the normal oauth process. If you just need to pull data or handle some creation routes that do not require a user action so be it use the personal access token. What i don't want to do is add more functionality which replaces an existing workflow already in place. I just want to deter them from using one or the other based on the route they are trying to hit. route 1 accepts personal token + oauth | Route2 only accepts oauth

Comment: and actually just testing this out... technically the Auth::user() for the personal access token is the user whom created it right... so it would not prompt them at all. 
I am ok with an application using a personal access token for certain things. but when taking action on a specifc route I do not want them to be able to submit anything. because technically they could submit to all the routes... and a logged in user (on their application) would not know the difference but on my side (api side) all submissions would look like the user whom created the token - not who is actually submit reques

Comment: I think i am going to have to create a "new" type of token outside the scope of passport to get what i need done.